# Comparing two z-score variables

Tags: correlation, z-score

Say I have 2 variables (height and weight) for 20 people. Each height and weight value will be converted into a z-score (calculated using age and gender dependent population norms).

Weight and height z-scores for the people (-3,-2) (-2,-1) (-1,0) etc

If I do a pearson correlation it will show me a strong positive correlation. What pearson's doesn't show is that weight is always smaller than height and the agreement between the two values isn't good. The goal of the study is to show that the weight z-score for each patient differs to the height z-score. The height z-score isn't a good replacement for the weight z-score.

Can I use something like the kappa coefficient for interrater reliability to show the agreement between the two variables by taking the difference of each height and weight measurement into account? Can I use the kappa coefficient for comparing 2 variables rather than for comparing the reliability of measurements?

If the answer is no, which test will best sum up my question?

Comment: Welcome to Stats.SE. May I suggest that you also study the z-scores of the Body Mass Index? Regarding the differences between the z-scores, you may also compute t-Student's tests. With respect to the differences, the z-scores in children for [height and weight are interpreted differently](https://www.who.int/nutgrowthdb/about/introduction/en/index2.html): low weight (wasting) may be related with short term hunger and low height (stunting) may be related with long term hunger.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. As paired student's t-test compares mean differences between the two observations, it will also not show me the agreement between these values.

Yes, the difference between height and weight are interpreted differently. But how did the researchers prove this?

Comment: @Ertxiem: "Regarding the differences between the z-scores, you may also compute t-Student's tests": Since z scores have a mean of zero the t test would test whether two groups each with a mean of zero have different means. p will be 1. See this: `set.seed(1);
x1 <- rnorm(100);
x2 <- 5 + rnorm(100);
t.test(x1, x2)` # p-value < 2.2e-16. But:
`zx1 <- scale(x1);
zx2 <- scale(x2);
t.test(zx1, zx2)`  #p-value = 1

Comment: With respect to the difference between height and weight, it came from clinical studies that found, when there is hunger, that it is easier for a child to recover from a low weight situation than from a low height situation (I'm sorry but I don't know the details of the studies).

Comment: As for the comparison between height and weight, it depends on the reference for the z-scores. If you compute the z-scores with respect to some international reference (e.g., IOTF, WHO, CDC) then the mean z-score of your sample may not be zero and the mean of the weight z-scores can be compared with the mean of the height z-scores. If you are computing z-scores with respect to your sample, then I agree that a t-Student's test will not make sense.

Comment: To my knowledge z scores always will result in a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1. See here for example https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/standard-score-2.php

Comment: Thank you for your responses. We took weight and height for each person and then calculated the z-score using WHO references. I did not compute my own z-scores using my data. When using student's t-test one group had a significantly lower mean z-score height and weight than the other group.